# Overloaded C++ function float parameters error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, floating-point, overloading

I've been programming a pair of overloaded C++ functions, one taking 2 integer parameters, and the other 2 floats.

But the codeblocks compiler says:

```
error: call of overloaded 'func(double, double)' is ambiguous
```

Why `double` if I'm specifying a `float`?

I'm using the two functions to sum their values and showing the result on `cout` inside them. Float values given as arguments are 1.14 and 3.33, not big floating numbers...

Someone knows? thx!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int a, int b) {
    cout << a+b;
}

void func(float a, float b) 
    cout << a+b;
}

int main() {
  func(3, 7);
  func(1.14, 3.33);

}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Because C++ specifies that float values get promoted to doubles.

Comment: what minds float values promoted to double then?

Comment: `double` isn’t `float`. Calling either function with `double` arguments requires a conversion, and both conversions have the same rank, so the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function call `func(1.14, 3.33)` is ambiguous because `1.14` and `3.33` are doubles and both can be converted to either `int` or `float`. Therefore the compiler does not know which function to call.

You can fix this by explicitly specifying the type of the constants `func(float(1.14), float(3.33))` or by changing the overload from `func(float, float)` to `func(double, double)`.

In this case, explicitly telling the compiler which type to use is probably a better idea.

Comment: Since they are literals you can just use `1.14f` and `3.33f`